# How to create a simple timer to execute a fun every second using setInterval?

Tags: datetime, timer, kotlin

I'm new to **[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-window-or-worker-global-scope/set-interval.html)**. I'd like to create a simple timer to execute `fun` every second. I've researched some approaches and found the [setInterval](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom/-window-or-worker-global-scope/set-interval.html). But I can't understand how to implement in the code. All I need is just execute `println("Hello, world!")` every second.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about setInterval (note that it's JS platform only !) but if you want to print "Hello world !" every seconds, here is a solution

```
fun doEverySeconds(action: () -> Unit) {
    thread {
        while (true) {
            action()
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    doEverySeconds {
        println("Hello world !")
    }
}
```

Or with the time as parameter

```
fun doEveryX(timeInMS : Long, action: () -> Unit) {
    thread {
        while (true) {
            action()
            Thread.sleep(timeInMS)
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    doEveryX(1200) {
        println("Hello world !")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to user3491043's answer, I'd like to also point out that you can use coroutines *or* Java's [`Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-).

Here's an example using coroutines:

```
async {
    while (true) {
        // Do whatever
        delay(interval)
    }
}
```